# System gets extremely slow while copying big files from USB

Tags: usb, 20.04, ram, system

My system gets extremely slow when I copy big files from my USB. The system gets so slow that the mouse cursor can't be moved. Some information about my laptop: i3, 4 GB RAM, and 1 TB HDD. Laptop works just fine when I'm doing normal work.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       1.1Gi       970Mi        75Mi       1.7Gi       2.3Gi
Swap:         7.4Gi          0B       7.4Gi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
udo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for : 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.00
       date: 03/22/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3e
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: TEAMGROUP-Ind-2400
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 010447E3
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 44
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 45
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 46
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df224000-df227fff
```

Comment: I think it must be a limitation of Files or Gnome as I have a Ryzen 3600 so not exactly a weak CPU and it brings my system to a crawl when I copy large files (16GB video files) in Ubuntu. For comparison, copying the same files in Manjaro KDE Edition, I do not experience the same slowdown. This is from two internal SSDs as well.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: he meant to run `sudo lshw -C memory`. You forgot the **memory** in that command.

Comment: What USB are you copying from? USB2 or USB3? Flash drive? Disk drive? Do you have a powered USB hub? Tell me the exact make/model # of your laptop.